# how to crop using the rect values? in android

Tags: java, android, rect

hi i am currently working on a project , i have the rectangle values which is top, left, bottom, right now i want to crop that portion,,, i will use this code to crop it by creating new bitmap

```
createBitmap(Bitmap source, int x, int y, int width, int height, Matrix m, boolean filter)
```

but the problem is, i dont know how to get the x and y coordinate of the rectangle ?, also the matrix and boolean filter? , please help me thanks

## java

## android

Comment: You can set false value on filter and an empty Matrix on m field.